# How do you find all uses of a font in a PDF or Illustrator document

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I have a collection of Illustrator files which get collected into a single PDF. Having attempted to remove all uses of a specific font throughout, I find that the font is still being embedded. How can I find which pages and where on the page that font is used?

Comment: The part "which pages" is rather easy to solve automatically/programatically with the help of (free) software tools. The part "and where on the page" is rather difficult: depending on the visual appearance of the pages, you may need to resort to rather expensive professional "PDF Preflight" software tools, such as Callas Software's "pdfToolbox" (or Acrobat Professional's builtin tool).

Comment: Finding which pages out of a large document would still get me a large part of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pdffonts.exe" commandline utility can indicate which fonts are used on which page. It's part of the .zip available here: ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdf-3.02pl4-win32.zip  and works without "installation".

Make yourself familiar with its use by opening a cmd.exe window and type:

```
pdffonts.exe -help
```

If you want to see which fonts are used on page 23 of one.pdf, use this command:

```
pdffonts.exe ^
    -f 23 ^
    -l 23 ^
    c:\path\to\one.pdf
```

If you want to see the fonts for page range 4-11 of two.pdf, use this command:

```
 for /l %i in (4,1,11) ^
    do (echo. page %i & ^
    pdffonts -f %i -l %i c:\path\to\two.pdf)
```